# Drop/Undo sudo privileges on .py file which runs inside a program which runs from sudo previleges

Tags: python, shell, ubuntu, file-permissions, sudo

I need to run a program from sudo privileges and I am running .py file inside the program. So when my program runs from sudo then it automatically calls/runs the .py file with sudo. I am running file like "./myFile.py arg1 arg2"

My requirement is that my program need to be run from sudo but when I runs/calls .py file inside program then it should runs as normal privileges ( without sudo).

If anybody has idea then pleas let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running the python file directly, run it as another user

```
su -c "./myFile.py arg1 arg2" another_user
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I run file as per suggested by you and it works. But when I wrote this line inside .sh file and run .sh file using sudo then it does not works and it says "(process:3572): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: Could not connect: Connection refused" on terminal.

Comment: Hmm. It could be an environment problem. Try passing the `-m` option: `su -m -c "./myFile.py arg1 arg2" another_user`

Comment: I have tried with -m way but on terminal it says "unable to create file '/home/myusername/.cache/dconf/user': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly." Would be great if you please try the same at your end and let me know the result. Btw thanks for your reply.

Comment: I mean, I don't have your python file, but `echo -e "su -c \"echo 'test'\"" myusername > tmp.sh && chmod +x tmp.sh && sudo ./tmp.sh` outputs `test`, so I can verify that `su -c` works in bash scripts if that is what you are concerned about. However, a quick look at aptitude reveals that of the packages available with names containing "dconf", none of them are installed. I would be pretty surprised if I got any dconf errors.

Comment: Please have a look on http://askubuntu.com/questions/643028/shell-script-to-remove-unity-launcherif-present-in-ubuntu-14-04-and-or-the-xf. This is the actual task which I want to do and .py file is also there .

Comment: I cannot exactly test that here. My only three machines are Windows, Mac and a headless Ubuntu server. None of those are exactly able to even show the Unity Launcher you want to get rid of. You could be having a similar problem to [this person](http://askubuntu.com/questions/457016/how-to-change-gsettings-via-remote-shell). You could try saving the script suggested in the [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/457023) and sourcing it before running the python script.

Comment: @ bytesized, Thanks for your reply. If anybody there who has any idea about the issue then please let me know.